# How to determine if dotnetcore-windowshosting has been installed

Tags: windows, registry, .net-core

I'm writing a script (chef) that will run periodically and keep an environment in a known state. One of the things that this script needs to do is install dotnetcore.x.x.x-WindowsHosting if it is not already. I'm trying to find a registry key or specific file that will only exist if windowshosting has been installed AND will NOT persist if it has been uninstalled. I'm finding this surprisingly difficult. This is what I've done so far:

1. Run the installer with Process Monitor running to see what registry keys were created, read, modified, yadda yadda. Nothing's jumping out to me.
2. Checked HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ for the key that notifies Control Panel that a program can be uninstalled. While the Windows Server Hosting entry does exist in 'Programs and Features', there is no associated registry key at the above location. This is real strange to me, as VC++ Redist is also installed from this installer, and it IS listed. Twice.
3. Followed the VC++ Redist reg key into C:\Program Data\Package Cache and dug around in there trying to find dotnetcore-WindowsHosting. I found it, but I'm not sure if this is safe to use.
4. Tried to find ANYTHING in Program Files (x86/64), AppData, Windows that could be used for this. I'm having a hard time telling if anything changed or was added from this install other than a lot of temp folders.

I'm at a loss, at this point. Does anyone have any idea where to find what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

ps: Hopefully this is appropriate for stackoverflow. Seems almost like a server fault question. Tangentially related to code, at least.

Comment: you may call 'dotnet --version' command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a registry key corresponding to the installation of dotnetcore server hosting. Unfortunately I have lost it, as I found a different mechanism to automatically install this application. Namely, chocolatey.

Turns out, regedit has a "find" functionality. Edit > Find. Just type dotnetcore into that, it'll take you to the registry entry.